# Prevent duplicate files polling using @InboundChannelAdapter annotaion

Tags: spring-integration

I am using `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotaion in a java class for polling files from a directory.

How can we prevent duplicate file polling in this?

Comment: You need to show your configuration so we have some context.

Comment: Hi Gary Russell, Its resolved using filter. I have an another question how can we implement file:outbound-channel-adapter using annotation? my requirement is to move one file from a location to another.

Comment: You should really ask this as a new question since it's unrelated. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans). Use a `@ServiceActivator` on a `@Bean` that's a `FileWritingMessageHandler`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure file polling process via Annotations you should do something like this:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "filesChannel", poller = @Poller(fixed-rate = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
     FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
     source.setDirectory(new File(INBOUND_PATH));
     source.setAutoCreateDirectory(false);
     source.setFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
     return source;
}
```

The same can be achieved with more simple way using [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl):

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(s -> s.file(tmpDir.getRoot()).patternFilter("*.sitest"),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
                .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
                .aggregate(a -> a.correlationExpression("1")
                        .releaseStrategy(g -> g.size() == 25))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("fileReadingResultChannel"))
                .get();
    }
```

Another your question can be resolved with the DSL as well, but it is definitely the separate SO question...

Comment: BTW, we are going to address this confuse in the Framework documentation: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3855